# ¿Como puedo añadir un intent en un fragment.class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un problema en un ***fragment.class*** y es que no puedo añadir *intents* ya que me dan errores y si los pongo en **MainActivity** no me da errores.

para que tenga una idea, *intent* que quiero añadir es este:

```
public void open2 (View view){

    Intent open2 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
    startActivity(open2);
}
```

y me da error en ***getPackageManager***.

Comment: Utiliza `getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox")`

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent open2 = new Intent(getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"));
open2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(open2);
```

Comment: Armen, es bueno contribuyas, sin embargo, si únicamente agregas código, esto no sera en realidad una respuesta, que te parece ai agregas una explicación de tu código. Revisa por favor [answer]. Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas realizar un `Intent` dentro de un `Fragment` es necesario tener un contexto, si te encuentras dentro dentro de un Fragment el contexto lo puedes obtener de la activity que contiene el Fragment usando `getActivity()`:

```
public void open2 (View view){

    Intent open2 = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
    startActivity(open2);
}
```